# outlook forward multiple emails at once by creating new rule

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Im trying to forward multiple emails at once to a default mail account.

Whe i try to select multiple emails and forward them, they are sending as attachments.

Is there any way of sending every selected items to one account as separated emails?

Comment: Which version of Outlook?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. More details are needed. Please tell us what version you are using, as well as what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. Take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook does not provide a straightforward way for individually forwarding multiple e-mails.

One workaround (described on the page below) involves creating a watch folder with a rule to forward using an Outlook rule.  Unfortunately, the group of recipients must be predetermined for the rule.

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1165-outlook-forward-multiple-emails.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a **free** way to achieve your goal: [Redirect Messages](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesRedirect/) utility. I recommend it because I'm one of its developers. With this tool, you can either select Outlook folder and redirect (forward) all messages in this folder or select required messages and use the right-click menu to redirect/forward them.

Answer (score 0):

Note O365 administration can be setup to spot mass sends and stop them. Using a Rule sends emails out rapidly enough to be caught. Workaround is more tedious as you have to send one by one but this can be eased by setting up a Quickstep to forward with the option “automatically send after one minute delay” – here you can click on an email and action and immediately move to the next one. Here you can get maybe 20 emails out a minute without the mass forward police catching you (if your administrators disallow autoforwarding)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).